# Is it possible to delete a managed package completely from packaging org?

Tags: managed-package, delete, uninstall

I have created a managed package that has 5 versions and now want to delete it entirely from this org. Is it possible? The package is not installed in any other org. The deprecate option appears for all versions of the package excluding the first one. It does not allow me to delete the package because of the versions.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's your main objective?

Comment: @DavidReed The client asked us to make some changes in the custom object Name field, we can not change it in the packaging org because it already has a release version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to delete the package completely.
You can revert the package to Beta for which you need to log a case with [Salesforce support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) team specifying the package ID and the version(s)(starts with #04t) that you want as reverted to beta.Make sure that the package version is not installed in any other org.

Considering this logic, to achieve what you want, ALL released versions need to be reverted to beta, and then you will be able to remove all components from the package, and add components as needed.

Ensure that you have reviewed the article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312548&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Note:If you delete the existing package then you will not be able to create a new one in the same org.